# Find the $n^{th}$ order derivative of $ y=x \log\frac{(x-1)}{(x+1)}$ by using leibnitz's formula of two function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

> Find the $n^{th}$ order derivative of $ y=x \log\frac{(x-1)}{(x+1)}$ by using leibnitz's formula of two function

I can not understand that how it is proved, so please somebody help me.I  tried but ,I am unable to find the answer.

Answer (score 1):

***HINT***:
$log(\frac{x+1}{x-1}) = log|x+1|-log|x-1|$

Comment: if $x>1$ and $log(\frac{x+1}{x-1}) = log(-x-1)-log(1-x)$ for  $x<-1$ In both cases $log(\frac{x+1}{x-1}) = log|x+1|-log|x-1|$